# How do I delete the first delimiter of file names in linux?

Tags: linux, filenames

I want to delete the first delimiter of file names in linux.

For example,

```
$ ls my_directory
a.b.c.txt a.b.d.txt a.b.e.txt
```

I want it to be like:

```
$ ls my_directory
ab.c.txt ab.d.txt ab.e.txt
```

I tried:

```
$ mv a.b* ab*
```

, but unfortunately this doesn't work.

What should I do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Depending on your shell, there are one of about 5 answers that can be given. The simplest being a *Parameter-Expansion with substring substitution* if using bash, or zsh, etc.. Otherwise multiple subshells will be needed. What is the output of `echo $SHELL`? Both `rename` from util-linux and `perl-rename` are also options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a replace once parameter expansion method if you're using Bash:

```
for f in a.b*; do
    mv -i -- "$f" "${f/.}"
done
```

See [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

If you're using a POSIX shell, you can use `${f%%.*}${f#*.}` or in the case of a known prefix like `a.b`, , simply `ab${f#a.b}`.